# External style sheets not applying styles

Tags: html, css

I have this page, to test a new layout for a category on a website at my new job:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/1.0.0/grids-responsive-min.css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="category-desc-grid" class="pure-g">

      <div class="pure-u">
        <p class="title"></p>

        <p class="details">
          Throw Style &amp; Fitted Style<br>
          71 Fabric Color Choices<br>
          Fire resistant. Passes NFPA 701-2010<br>
          Full Color Dye Sublimation
        </p>

        <a href="#" class="button">Buy/View 24 Hour Tablecloths</a>
      </div>

      <div class="pure-u-1-2">
        <p class="title">Single Color Front Panel, Fitted Table Colors &amp; Throws</p>

        <p class="details">
          4ft, 5ft, 6ft, 8ft<br>
          74 Fabric Color Choices,<br>
          including neon colors.<br>
          Fire resistant. Passes<br>
          NFPA 701-2010
        </p>

        <a href="#" class="button">Available in 1, 2, or 3 Day Production</a>
      </div>

      <div class="pure-u-1-2">
        <p class="title">Full Color Print Front Panel</p>

        <p class="details">
          Additional Panel Print $99<br>
          Fitted &amp; Throw Style<br>
          4ft, 5ft, 6ft, 8ft<br>
          71 Fabric Choices<br>
          F.R. - NFPA 701-2010
        </p>

        <a href="#" class="button">Available in 1, 2, or 3 Day Production</a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

All of the stylesheets included are the mass that they have included in the head of the page that this code is to be inserted into, save for the last one, the [Pure Grid](https://purecss.io/grids/). This is the one in question which will not apply any of its styles. As you can see I have the classes from that stylesheet in my HTML, but no styles are being attributed to them upon inspection. Styles from the stylesheets prior, however, are being applied.

Why

I've removed the grid stylesheet altogether and added one simple line: `.display-grid .half { display: inline-block; width: 50%; max-width: 50%; }` but it will only split into halves if I exclude the width rule. Unbelievable.

I just added the Bootstrap grid standalone.

Comment: any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Are you getting any 404 errors in the console?

Comment: there is a 404 on this resource http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/base/default/tm/configurableswatches/css/swatches.css check it out

Comment: Its quite likely a webserver issue, where the files are restricted to the same domain.  What is the webserver, Apache, IIS ?

Comment: @Splatten I don't think so, the resource doesn't seem to exist...

Comment: @DaFois, which one, I just tried the first and it opened fine.

Comment: @SPlatten Look at my previous comment...

Comment: @DaFois, true that one doesn't exist.

Comment: Right ok that doesn't exist I removed it just in case that would make any difference but as I assumed it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your code on my system. The inspect console complained that no character encoding was declared, so i inserted a `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` snippet in the `<head>` tags.

Also, I looked at the Pure Grid css file. It looks like some elements are missing when you used the class names. For example, I changed `"pure-u"` to `"pure-u-sm-1-24"` and it worked in my browser.

Comment: Well ok I added the charset fair enough, and that's weird when I try for each it works but I need 1-2, I tried 12-24 and that won't work either. Ridiculous.

Comment: @CalyneMartel I read the documentation on https://purecss.io/start/ and you will need to copy their CDN code block (from said page) and paste it into your document, before all other CSS links. That worked for me.

Comment: Oh BEFORE the others. I should have thought of that. Oh well, went with Bootstrap. Thank you though, good to know.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/js/tm/easylightbox/lightbox/css/lightbox.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/default/delivery/css/reset.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/default/delivery/css/boxes.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/default/delivery/css/styles.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/default/delivery/css/menu.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/aitpagecache.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/base/default/crimson/catalog/css/catalog.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/base/default/magmodules/snippets/snippets.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/base/default/magmodules/snippets/breadcrumbs.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.premiertablelinens.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/tm/easytabs.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/1.0.0/grids-responsive-min.css" media="all" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/base-min.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/grids-min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="category-desc-grid" class="pure-g">
      <div class="pure-u">
        <p class="title"></p>
        <p class="details">
          Throw Style &amp; Fitted Style<br>
          71 Fabric Color Choices<br>
          Fire resistant. Passes NFPA 701-2010<br>
          Full Color Dye Sublimation
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="button">Buy/View 24 Hour Tablecloths</a>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1-2">
        <p class="title">Single Color Front Panel, Fitted Table Colors &amp; Throws</p>
        <p class="details">
          4ft, 5ft, 6ft, 8ft<br>
          74 Fabric Color Choices,<br>
          including neon colors.<br>
          Fire resistant. Passes<br>
          NFPA 701-2010
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="button">Available in 1, 2, or 3 Day Production</a>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1-2">
        <p class="title">Full Color Print Front Panel</p>
        <p class="details">
          Additional Panel Print $99<br>
          Fitted &amp; Throw Style<br>
          4ft, 5ft, 6ft, 8ft<br>
          71 Fabric Choices<br>
          F.R. - NFPA 701-2010
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="button">Available in 1, 2, or 3 Day Production</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above you forgot to add two more files like- base-min.js and grids-min.js